# String functions to generate dynamic query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

`Select * from MyTable` gives the following result

```
AttributeID                          AttributeName
------------------------------------ ------------------------
6B93119B-263B-4FED-AA89-198D26A3A3C4 DOB
E27DBA94-F387-460A-BC02-84878692BDF6 Sex
ABF3B85C-0DEA-44FE-857A-AC63520F7294 History
```

Now I want to generate a dynamic query in the following format (to be used with PIVOT)

```
 SELECT 
  [6B93119B-263B-4FED-AA89-198D26A3A3C4] DOB,

  [E27DBA94-F387-460A-BC02-84878692BDF6] Sex,

  [ABF3B85C-0DEA-44FE-857A-AC63520F7294] History
```

How can I do it in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 0):

The following produces the desired result for me:

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Query = 'SELECT ';

WITH Data AS (
    SELECT '6B93119B-263B-4FED-AA89-198D26A3A3C4' AS AttributeID, 'DOB' AS AttributeName

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'E27DBA94-F387-460A-BC02-84878692BDF6', 'Sex'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'ABF3B85C-0DEA-44FE-857A-AC63520F7294', 'History'
)
SELECT @Query = @Query + '''' + AttributeID + ''' ' + AttributeName + ', '
FROM Data

SET @Query = SUBSTRING(@Query, 1, LEN(@Query) - 1);

SELECT @Query
```

**Edit:** Just to be clear, the section of SQL in the above sample beginning "WITH Data AS (" and ending at the close bracket (")") is just there as sample data. You can omit it entirely, so the sample becomes:

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Query = 'SELECT ';

SELECT @Query = @Query + '''' + AttributeID + ''' ' + AttributeName + ', '
FROM MyTable

SET @Query = SUBSTRING(@Query, 1, LEN(@Query) - 1);

SELECT @Query
```

Comment: @Looks nice. But I can not assure that the number of rows in `MyTable`. Some times there may be 'Sex' in the table and sometimes may not.

Comment: The above code works no matter how many rows are in the Data table (which is the equivalent of your MyTable). The only case where it won't work is if there are zero rows.

Comment: No. My question is I can not hard code `SELECT 'E27DBA94-F387-460A-BC02-84878692BDF6', 'Sex'
`

Comment: As you seem to have noticed in your answer below, the code works even if you omit the section from "WITH Data AS (" down to the close bracket ")". This section was there only as a sample, to allow the code to work without having the actual MyTable table (which I don't have on my system).

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT '

SELECT @query = @query + '[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),AttributeID) + '] ' + AttributeName + ',' 
FROM MyTable

PRINT @query
```